# What does it mean for a managed object context to be "non-generational"?

Tags: swift, core-data

From the documentation for `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `var viewContext`,

> This property contains a reference to the NSManagedObjectContext that
>   is created and owned by the persistent container which is associated
>   with the main queue of the application. This context is created
>   automatically as part of the initialization of the persistent
>   container.
>
> This context is associated directly with the
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and is non-generational by default.

What does non-generational mean in this context?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/accessing_data_when_the_store_has_changed

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like, before there were child contexts, generations allowed contexts to be nestled up to the persistent store but without having to merge the changes immediately. These days, if you have a main object context and a child of that context, you could just keep track of changed objects at the child object context and merge them when you're ready.

Comment: I actually don't know enough to speak to that, I just thought that documentation had what you were looking for. Shot in the dark